# Calculate average time with Luxon

Tags: javascript, time, average, luxon

Does anyone know of an elegant way to calculate the average time of a series of date times?

So far I figured I can convert to an integer (e.g. seconds) and calcualte the average and then convert back to a Luxon object, but I am afraid that might bring in some errors? Or is that still the safest/best way to do it?

Example data set:

```
var datez = [
    {time: "Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"},
    {time: "Wed Jan 02 2020 21:10:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"},
    {time: "Wed Jan 03 2020 11:34:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"},
    {time: "Wed Jan 04 2020 22:50:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"},
    {time: "Wed Jan 05 2020 12:12:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"}]
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking for.  What would the desired output be from the examples you gave?  Are you looking for the average time of day without respect to the date? Or something else?  Also,  is your input really strings in that exact format? Or are you starting with `Date` objects or some other type of value?